# Get child's class name from parent

Tags: c++

I want to get child's class name from parent pointer.

```
class Parent{
}
class Child: Parent {
}

Parent* parent = new Child;
cout << typeid(parent).name(); //it prints "Parent", but I want to print "Child"
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, the class has to be polymorphic, i.e. have at least one virtual function. Normally, you'd make this the destructor, because base classes without virtual destructors are a recipe for trouble.

Then, you'll need to query the type of the *object* and not of the *pointer* to it. Put together:

```
class Parent
{
public:
  virtual ~Parent() = default;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
};

Parent *parent = new Child;
cout << typeid(*parent).name();
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37c6ad7ea2e6d3e8)

Comment: " base classes without virtual destructors are a recipe for trouble" can you explain this?

Comment: @Oli Deleting through a pointer-to-parent is UB if the parent doesn't have a virtual dtor.

Answer (score 1):

As [cppreference explains](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), `parent` needs to be a polymorphic object.

In other words, adding at least 1 `virtual` method to your `Parent` will get you your desired result.